# Text property in custom Control loses value

Tags: vb.net, controls, properties

I am making a custom button control and am having some difficulty with my Text property. Anything I type in only stays while the form designer window is open. When I close the form designer and reopen it, my Text property resets to "". Also if I run the program, it loses the value entered at design time.

I also have an Image property for my control which is working just fine.

Here's some of my code:

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class BlackButton

Private iText As String
Private iImage As Image

''' <summary>
''' Gets/Sets the text displayed in the button.
''' </summary>
<Browsable(True), Description("Gets or sets the text displayed on the button")> _
Public Shadows Property Text() As String
    Get
        Return iText
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        iText = value
        ReDrawMe()
    End Set
End Property

''' <summary>
''' Gets/Sets the image to be displayed on the button
''' </summary>
<Browsable(True), Description("Gets or sets the image displayed on the button")> _
Public Shadows Property Image() As Image
    Get
        Return iImage
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Image)
        iImage = value
        ReDrawMe()
    End Set
End Property
```

I have carefully combed through my code and made sure I'm not resetting it anywhere.

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: Why the data stay put after the form closes?

Comment: It's a button control. When you enter a caption for the button at design time, it should still be there when you run the program or close then re-open the form designer. My control isn't doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work adding a property :

```
<Browsable(True), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)> _
Public Overrides Property Text() As String
    Get
        Return MyBase.Text
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        MyBase.Text = value
        LabInfo.Text = MyBase.Text
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Yes, this is what finally worked for me; I was missing the DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible) part.

Answer (score 1):

I once meet this problem. Just delete the Shadows keyword. I don't know if Override can work there, but if not, just ignore the VS warning about Text and Image properties.

EDIT: I don't know why you didn't succeed with the `Overrides` keyword. Only `Image` property forced me using `Overloads` instead. Here's my code:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
```

Public Class UserControl1

```
Dim _Text As String
Dim _Image As Image

<Browsable(True), Description("Gets or sets the text displayed on the button")> _
Overrides Property Text() As String
    Get
        Return _Text
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _Text = value
        'This line just for update
        'the UI when I design to check
        'if the values are saved.
        MyBase.Text = value
    End Set
End Property

<Browsable(True), Description("Gets or sets the image displayed on the button")> _
Overloads Property Image() As Image
    Get
        Return _Image
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Image)
        _Image = value
        'ReDrawMe()
    End Set
End Property
```

End Class

Comment: OK, I've tried removing the Shadows keyword like this: 'Public Property Text() As String' No luck there. Then I tried it with the Overrides keyword. Still no luck.

Comment: Please wait. I met that one and solved it. I will check my old project and edit my answer soon (and leave a comment after that). EDIT1: And, please tell me the .NET version you are using. I've heard some members in my forum have bad luck with this, too. EDIT2: And, what do you inherit this class from? Control or Button?

Comment: Finally solved it by just renaming my property to TextShown. Not the most elegant, but nothing else seemed to work for me.  @W.N. - Its based on Control.